# How to change theme with zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using [this configuration](https://github.com/nicknisi/dotfiles) on my mac(unix) to customize my shell. I am using zsh instead of bash and there are too many things along with zsh. This `.dotfile` configuration contains `vim, zsh, git, homebrew, nvm, nginx, neovim` and there respective themes and configurations. With `Oh-my-zsh` I can customize so many themes but here `zsh` is controlling my shell and `~/.zshrc` is a symlink created with `.dotfiles/zsh/zshrc.symlink` file  which I am using from Github's .dotfile bundle. I have renamed oh-my-zsh's version of zshrc file to ~/.zshrc.bak. Also, adding theme configuation to `zsh's` version of `~\zshrc` file doesn't work. How, can I change theme with `zsh`?

**zshrc's symlink from ~/.dotfiles**

```
❯ cat ~/.zshrc
# Ruby Motion android tool
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/sdk
export RUBYMOTION_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rubymotion-android/ndk

export DOTFILES=$HOME/.dotfiles
export ZSH=$DOTFILES/zsh

# display how long all tasks over 10 seconds take
export REPORTTIME=10

[[ -e ~/.terminfo ]] && export TERMINFO_DIRS=~/.terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo

# define the code directory
# This is where my code exists and where I want the `c` autocomplete to work from exclusively
if [[ -d ~/code ]]; then
    export CODE_DIR=~/code
fi

# source all .zsh files inside of the zsh/ directory
for config ($ZSH/**/*.zsh) source $config

if [[ -a ~/.localrc ]]; then
    source ~/.localrc
fi


# initialize autocomplete
autoload -U compinit
compinit

for config ($ZSH/**/*completion.sh) source $config

export EDITOR='nvim'

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# add /usr/local/sbin
if [[ -d /usr/local/sbin ]]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
fi

# adding path directory for custom scripts
export PATH=$DOTFILES/bin:$PATH

# check for custom bin directory and add to path
if [[ -d ~/bin ]]; then
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
fi

[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color

# install rbenv
if hash rbenv 2>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

if [[ -d ~/.rvm ]]; then
    PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
fi

# alias git to hub
if hash hub 2>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(hub alias -s)"
fi

# source nvm
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

if hash brew 2>/dev/null; then
    source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
    source `brew --prefix`/etc/profile.d/z.sh
fi


# Base16 Shell
# if [ -z "$THEME" ]; then
    export THEME="base16-eighties"
# fi
if [ -z "$BACKGROUND" ]; then
    export BACKGROUND="dark"
fi


BASE16_SHELL="$DOTFILES/.config/base16-shell/$THEME.$BACKGROUND.sh"
# [[ -s $BASE16_SHELL ]] && source $BASE16_SHELL
source $BASE16_SHELL
```

**oh-my-zsh's version of zshrc file which doesn't work.**

```
❯ cat .zshrc.bak
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.oh-my-zsh


ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git)

# User configuration

export PATH="/Users/abhimanyuaryan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/abhimanyuaryan/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Even if I add `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"` in ~/.zshrc. The theme doesn't change. It's still the same which Nick provided.

I asked him. He said your oh-my-zsh is clashing with my configurations. Create your own. I don't want to create my own because I am fairly new to all this stuff. Once I am good at tmux, vim, and all this stuff I'll create my own. Until then I just want to use this .dotfiles configuration. Please help me to customize my theme with this configuration. Also,  Please help me to understand difference b/w zsh and oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Now it is 2017. What did you learn?

Comment: Have you tried exporting instead of just setting ZSH_THEME? I have `alias resource='source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh'` and `alias restyle='(){ export ZSH_THEME="$@" && resource }'`, so for example, all I have to write is `restyle sorin`. (This expects `export ZSH=~/path/to/oh-my-zsh`.) (As an aside, some of my .zshrc is sensitive to double-sourcing, so I added include guards and generally just source oh-my-zsh.) For what it's worth, I tried setting ZSH_THEME without exporting, and it worked anyway. Please take a moment to update if you still have this environment or one like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you're done editing your `~/.zshrc`, in a shell prompt run the command `source ~/.zshrc`.
it will read the config from `~/.zshrc` and it will apply it, it's like reload your config.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @John P above in the comments as it's really his answer but for those wanting a way to change zsh theme "on the fly" without editing and re-sourcing the config, simply define this alias in your `.zshrc`

```
alias ztheme='(){ export ZSH_THEME="$@" && source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh }'
```

Usage:

```
ztheme blinks
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks man.

Comment: First of all: thanks for showing me that there's lambda functions in ZSH, I didn't know! Secondly: Is there any benefit to defining this as an alias rather than a (named) function?